# List of Android devices with their version DVM/ART

Tags: android, dalvik

Does anybody know list of **Android devices** with their current **version DVM / ART**?

Like:
`Android 5.0.2  API 21   ART 2.1.0
Android 4.4.3   API 19   ART 1.6.0 (?)
Android 2.3.3   API 10   DVM 1.4.0`

- OS version
- API level
- **DVM/ART version**

*Couldn't found anything in WHOLE Internet... even in their docs: https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html*

Comment: It's a VALID programming question(for compatibility) and NEVER asked before.. why downvote

Comment: There may not be a 1-to-1 mapping here, especially because manufacturers are free to modify the OS, so they may use a different version of art/dalvik than the stock Android OS. And from what I vaguely recall, dalvik was never really versioned in a useful way anyway.

Comment: Also, Why do you think you need this? Maybe the reason that this information isn't available is because there are other, better ways to go about doing whatever it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

try this bash script - it will print all possible properties from devices in adb

```
echo "============================"
echo "Android Device Specificatios"
echo "============================"
adb wait-\for-device
echo "> Manufacturer"
adb shell getprop ro.product.manufacturer
echo "> Name"
adb shell getprop ro.product.name
echo "> Model"
adb shell getprop ro.product.model
echo "> Android version"
adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release
echo "> Platform"
adb shell getprop ro.board.platform
echo "> CPU"
adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi
echo "> CPU.abi2"
adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi2
echo "> Description"
adb shell getprop ro.build.description
echo "> Fingerprint"
adb shell getprop ro.build.fingerprint
echo "> GSM Flexversion"
adb shell getprop ro.gsm.flexversion
echo "> Locale language"
adb shell getprop ro.product.locale.language
echo "> Locale region"
adb shell getprop ro.product.locale.region
echo "> Wifi channels"
adb shell getprop ro.wifi.channels
echo "> Board platform"
adb shell getprop ro.board.platform
echo "> Product board"
adb shell getprop ro.product.board
echo "> Display ID"
adb shell getprop ro.build.display.id
echo "> Serial number"
adb get-serialno
echo "> GSM IMEI"
adb shell getprop gsm.baseband.imei
echo "> Version incremental"
adb shell getprop ro.build.version.incremental
echo "> Version SDK"
adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk
echo "> Version codename"
adb shell getprop ro.build.version.codename
echo "> Version release"
adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release
echo "> Build date"
adb shell getprop ro.build.date
echo "> Build type"
adb shell getprop ro.build.type
echo "> Build user"
adb shell getprop ro.build.user
echo "----------------------------"
```

rest should be super easy : )

Comment: Thanks, but this is for the Current CONNECTED device... not ALL of them.  And rest is hard, not this one :)